# How can I create a self closing tag using JDOM

Tags: java, tags, self, jdom

I could find in Jdom api any function to create self closing xml tag like the `<selfClosingTag />` below.

For example, I need to create the following content:

```
<parentTag>
  <selfClosingTag />
  <firstChild>......    </firstChild>
  <secondChild>......    </secondChild>
</parentTag>
```

Can someone please tell me how. Please tell me I should not do it because this kind of self-closing tag is required in mathml document.

Thanks,
  Chepukha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any element you create, that you don't add any child nodes to, will be empty. An empty element can be represented as `<element/>` or `<element></element>`. Which one shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Great! Thanks Json for the link and mwittrock for the explanation.

Comment: IMHO: It matters at the moment you need to deal with really big XML file full of empty elements.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like modifying your `XMLOutputter` like this should do the trick:

```
outputter.setFormat(outputter.getFormat().setExpandEmptyElements(false));
```

See the [javadoc for `setExpandEmptyElements`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/Format.html#setExpandEmptyElements%28boolean%29).